# Calculate an expression with css units

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a function named **val()** whose code is given below :

```js
var antiString = function(obj) {
  return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')()
};

var val = function(str) {
  var calc = str.replace(/px|cm|vh|vw|em|rem|%|mm|in|pt|pc|ex|ch|vmin|vmax/gm, '');
  var unit = str.replace(/-|\+|\*|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9\//gm, '');
  var value = antiString(calc).toString() + unit;
  return value;
};

// Now usage :
console.log(
  val("30px/2"),  // => 15px
  val("60vh/3") // => 20vh
)

// But when :
console.log(
  val("30px + 20px"), // => 50px px
  val("100% - 100%"), // => 0% %
  val("100% / 50%"), // => 2% %
)
```

I am not understanding how to deal with these problems. So where to update my function such that the units never repeat but numbers can ? I assume it will be something like this :

```
  val("30px - 20px"); // => 10px
  val("30% / 30%"); // => 1
  val("50% + 30%"); // => 80%
  val("25vh - 25vh"); // => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably take help of the mathematical operators. Assume that you have two quantaties, "50%" & "100%", as given above. Now try to find out the symbol between them. If it's a "+", or "-", then don't remove the "%", or if it's "/" just remove it. It can go something like this :

```
if ( contains("+") || contains("-") ) {
   // Code such that % don't get remove
} 
else if ( contains("/") ) {
  // Code such that % gets removed
}
```

Here, the contains() is just to make you understand, it's not a pre-defined function. Now what can you do to find out the symbol out ? It's not that perfect, but yay you can use regex ! For e.g. we had the quantaties "50%" & "100%", you can do /%(.*?)%/gm to find the content between, then remove all the empty spaces, letters and numbers, which can be done again by regex. Therefore I think you get a preety sure idea. Well it's not a perfect solution, but I think you can come arround with it ! As @Anonymous told this is gonna be a complex function, but not an impossible one.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the units are the same, you can remove the second unit using [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var antiString = function(obj) {
   return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')()
 };

 var val = function(str) {
   var calc = str.replace(/px|cm|vh|vw|em|rem|%|mm|in|pt|pc|ex|ch|vmin|vmax/gm, '');
   var unit = str.replace(/-|\+|\*|0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9\//gm, '').split(/\s/)[0];
   // Update from comment
   if (unit === '%') { unit = ''; }
   var value = antiString(calc).toString() + unit;
   return value;
 };
```

Comment: That worked thanks !! But is there any way such that 100% - 100% = 0 & 100% / 50% = 2, since the present code says 100% / 50% = 2%

Comment: @ArcanadianArc Yes, see the updated answer. You remove the unit when it’s `%`.

Comment: @ArcanadianArc There is no way to deal with those cases without making the code a lot more complex. A simple `10px + 10%` will not be possible to calculate. It depends on how your input is created.

Comment: You’re welcome @ArcanadianArc. Good luck with the fixes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203609/discussion-between-arcanadian-arc-and-anonymous).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex that contains all the units, as you've defined them anyway:

```js
var antiString = function(obj) {
  return Function('"use strict";return (' + obj + ')')()
};

const unitsArray = ['px', 'cm', 'vh', 'vw', 'em', 'rem', '%', 'mm', 'in', 'pt', 'pc', 'ex', 'ch', 'vmin', 'vmax'];
const unitsRegex = new RegExp(unitsArray.join('|'), 'gm');

var val = function(str) {
  var calc = str.replace(unitsRegex, '');
  var unit = str.match(unitsRegex)[0];
  var value = antiString(calc).toString() + unit;
  
  console.log(value);
  return value;
};

val("30px/2"); // => 15px
val("60vh/3"); // => 20vh
val("30px + 20px"); // => 50px
val("100% - 100%"); // => 0%
val("100% / 50%"); // => 2%
```